# add 7 days constraint in Schedule Optimization in PuLP

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I want to create an optimal meal plan with minimum sugar intake for 
7 days but the everyday diet plan should include food from 3 different categories. How do I add constraint that I could get food from 3 different food categories and give meal plan for 7 days?

my dataframe is as follows:

```
id      name               energy   sugar   Food_Groups
1       4-Grain Flakes      140     58.8    Breakfast
2       Beef Mince, Fried   1443    8.0     Meat
3       Pork                1000    3.0     Meat
4       cake                1200    150     Sweet
5       cheese              1100    140     Sweet
6       Juice               700     85      Drink
7       cabbage             60      13      vegetarian
8       cucumber            10      10      vegetarian
9       eggs                45      30      Breakfast
```

I created a prob variable, formulated objective function, created dictionary variable, added constraints, and solved as follows

```
# Create the 'prob' variable to contain the problem data
prob = LpProblem("Simple Diet Problem",LpMinimize)
#create data variables and dictionary
food_items = list(df['name'])
calories = dict(zip(food_items,df['energy']))
sugars = dict(zip(food_items,df['sugar']))

food_vars =LpVariable.dicts("Food",food_items,lowBound=0,cat='Integer')

#Building the LP problem by adding the main objective function.
prob += lpSum([sugars[i]*food_vars[i] for i in food_items])

#adding calorie constraint
prob += lpSum([calories[f] * food_vars[f] for f in food_items]) >= 
1800.0, "CalorieMinimum"
prob += lpSum([calories[f] * food_vars[f] for f in food_items]) <= 
2200.0, "CalorieMaximum"

prob.writeLP("SimpleDietProblem.lp")

prob.solve()

print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
```

I want to know how to make a menu for 7 days? I tried the following code but It repeats the same foods

```
    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
for i in days:
    print(days)
    prob.writeLP("SimpleDietProblem.lp")
    prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD())
    print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
    print("Therefore, the optimal balanced diet consists of\n"+"-")
    for v in prob.variables():
        if v.varValue:
            print(v.name , "=", v.varValue)
            print("The total sugar of this balanced diet is: {}".format(round(value(prob.objective),2)))
```

Comment: I think you will need to add a binary variable indicating whether each category has been used, then add a constraint requiring at least 3 of those variables to equal 1.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Please let me know what to do next after creating categiries as follows?

Comment: Do you want at least 3 food groups each day, or across the 7 days. If it's each day then the problem for each day is the same so you would expect the optimal solution each day to be the same.

Comment: I want 3 food groups each day. How do I get a different set of foods in different days?

Comment: @kabdulla I want "meat" on alternate days and "Vegetables" on alternate days. How do I get it?

Comment: @Khaned what have you tried already? It might help if you explain your constraints in algebraic form instead of (or in addition to) in PuLP code.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 I want to minimize sugar intake, my calories should be close to 1000, I want to have "Meat" and "Vegetarian" food_groups on alternate days. The menu should be for 10 days.

Comment: I understand that that is a description in words of what you are trying to achieve. I am asking how you tried to formulate it in your optimization problem.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 As shown above I converted my dataframe into dictionary formats, used lpSum to formulate my objective i-e lpMinimize, added constraint on calories and wrote a loop for prob.solve() over days.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Since I have to make a linear objective function, so I formulated my objective function as sugar * foods. And used LpMinimize.

Comment: Here is what I am asking. You have a constraint saying you must consume at least 1800 calories. Algebraically, you could write that as `sum_{f in food_items}  calories[f] * food_vars[f] >= 1800`. In PuLP, you write it as `prob += lpSum([calories[f] * food_vars[f] for f in food_items]) >= 1800.0`. You did all that already. Now you are saying you want some new constraints, and I am asking you to first try to write those constraints yourself, algebraically and/or in PuLP. That is a more reasonable way to go about it than asking us to just formulate the code for you.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 I value your comments. I have shown that looping over prob.solve gives the same solution for different days, But I want to add "Vegetarian" and "Meat" on alternate days.

Comment: Your formulation does not make use of `days` at all, as far as I can tell. You will need to add an index for the day to your decision variables and adjust your objective function and constraints accordingly. Then, add a new constraint requiring alternating meat and vegetarian days. I'm sorry, but I think I might be at the end of the help that I can provide on this one.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 I used this but It didn't work `# Creates a list of the Food_groups
food_choices = list(df['Food_Groups'])

food_chosen = LpVariable.dicts("Chosen",food_choices,0,1,cat='Integer')            
# Creates a list of the Days
Days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

days_menu = LpVariable.dicts("days_menu",Days,0,1,cat='Integer')

#updating my objective function
prob += lpSum([sugars[i]*food_vars[i]*days_menu[i]*food_chosen[i] for i in 
food_items]) `